# Looping in entities hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I have two entities and when I want to get `grade.getSubcompetence()`. Error happens when i save entity, because subcompetence data null. When i debug i see error:

> 'java.lang.StackOverflowError' exception. Cannot evaluate _$$_jvstea5_f.toString()

#### grade entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString(exclude = {"subcompetence"})
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@Table(name = "GRADE")
public class Grade {
    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "SUBCOMPETENCE_ID", nullable = false)
    private Subcompetence subcompetence;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "LEVEL_ID", nullable = false)
    private Level level;
}
```

#### subcompetence entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@Table(name = "SUBCOMPETENCE")
public class Subcompetence {

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "subcompetence",
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Grade> grades;
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you also post the piece of code which is throwing this error?

Comment: @robot_alien updated

Comment: Hard to relate from the image, post the looping snippet here, seems a problem there itself

Comment: Also, I think the code is getting into a cyclic structure...

Comment: In all join column add `@JsonIgnore` annotation .

Answer (score 1):

try adding `@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude="grades")` in your Subcompetence class

Comment: it's also don't help(

Answer (score 0):

Add add `@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)` and `JsonIgnore` like below

```
  @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "subcompetence",
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JsonIgnore
private List<Grade> grades;
```

Comment: Remove  `@ToString(exclude = {"subcompetence"})` and check i came across this issue .

Comment: did you remove `@JsonManagedReference` and `  @JsonBackReference` from others class?

Comment: yes, i'm remove this annotations over grades and subcompetence fields